# The number of solutions for infinite power series equations $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k z^k=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, power-series

For polynomial equations we have the fundamental theorem of algebra, but what about infinite power series equations?

For example, by using Taylor series for different functions we can have:

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

So the equation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=1$$

Has infinitely many solutions $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$.

The exponential equation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=2$$

Has one real solution $x=\ln 2$, but infinitely many complex solutions $x=\ln 2+2i \pi n$.

On the other hand, geometric series equations have only finite number of solutions, since they can be expressed in closed form. In fact, they may have even less solutions than their closed form polynomial, because they have the restriction of $|x|<1$ to converge.

Binomial series equation, for example the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ can also have only a finite number of solutions, despite them being infinite series.

> Is there a general theorem about numer of solutions for an infinite power series equation? Or some works dedicated to this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there can only be a countable number of zeros because a power series is like a polynomial of infinite degree and they even often factor like polynomials.  So for example $\cos x=c\Pi_{n\in\Bbb Z}(x-r_n)$ where the $r_n$ are the roots of $\cos x$ and $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For entire functions (i.e. functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ which are analytic on the entire complex plane), there is a result called Jensen's theorem which relates the number of zeros to the order of growth of the function.

Also, an entire function is characterized (up to an exponential factor) by its zeros, according to Hadamard's factorization theorem.

Comment: To clarify, Hadamard's theorem applies to entire functions of finite order.

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant theorem: the zeros of (non identically null) analytical functions (functions that are locally power series) are isolated. This means that the set of zeros can't be, for example, a curve. More generally, the set of zeros can't have an accumulation point.